# Sending IV with cipher text

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am encrypting my message with a constant secret key and random IV using `AES/CTR/NoPadding` in Java.

I plan to prepend the IV to the cipher text and then `Base64` encode it.

Now, there is one problem that is bothering me. There can be multiple `IV` + Cipher text combinations that can result in my original message. Isn't that a problem? Also, is it safe to send IV as such (i.e. prepend/append to the cipher text) or there is some procedure that I should follow?

I am relatively new to cryptography, so pardon me if it's very simple question. I couldn't find any satisfying answer to this.

#### EDIT:

```
public static String encrypt(String message) {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
        byte[] iv = generateRandomIV();
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, SECRET_KEY, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

        byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes("utf-8"));
        return DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(concat(iv, cipherText));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static String decrypt(String encryptedMessage) {
    try {
        byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(encryptedMessage);
        byte[] iv = getIV(bytes);
        byte[] cipherText = getCipherText(bytes);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, SECRET_KEY, new IvParameterSpec(iv));

        return new String(cipher.doFinal(cipherText));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return encryptedMessage;
    }
}

private static byte[] getIV(byte[] bytes) {
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, 0, 16);
}

private static byte[] getCipherText(byte[] bytes) {
    return Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes, 16, bytes.length);
}
```

and then

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(decrypt("wVroKV1UnL2NXiImS83hLKpLLJKk"));
    System.out.println(decrypt("Q0tWAMZDhqMo0LbtEY7lF9D8Dkor"));
}
```

Both these produce same output -- "goody"

Comment: Can you cite your source for "there can be multiple IV + ciphertext combinations that result in my original message"?  Under a single key, I don't think this is true.

Comment: @LukePark - Added the code to the question

Comment: Ahhh, I misunderstood what you meant.  What you are doing is perfectly acceptable.  You should probably use a proper padding mode and add an HMAC, however.

Comment: @LukePark - proper padding mode?

Comment: Use `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` instead.

Comment: @LukePark - Could you please explain why it is better?

Comment: Because without proper padding you can't encrypt data that is any length other than a multiple of the blocksize.

Comment: @LukePark - I see. thanks. Also, why HMAC?

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were using CBC mode not CTR.  You should stick with the original no padding, my mistake.  The HMAC means you can detect changes to the ciphertext.  Without an HMAC, or authenticated mode like GCM, your ciphertext could be modified and you wouldn't ever know.

Comment: @LukePark - Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There can be multiple IV + Cipher text combinations that can result in my original message. Isn't that a problem?

The reason that you're using different IV's is that you can send the same message twice using the same key, with different ciphertext.

If it would generate the same ciphertext an adversary would know that the same message was send, leaking information about the message. So the idea of the IV **is** that it generates a different ciphertext and in most cases that is beneficial rather than a problem.

If it is a problem depends on your protocol. Note that the ciphertext length may still show information about the plaintext (i.e. "Affirmative, Sergeant" will of course be different than the encryption of "No").

You'll need an authentication tag / MAC value to protect against change of the message. Furthermore, you may want to include something like a message sequence number to make sure that replay attacks don't happen.

However, the deeper you go the more complex encryption becomes. If you require secure transport then in the end it is infinitely easier to use TLS or SSH (or any other applicable transport layer security).

> Also, is it safe to send IV as such (i.e. prepend/append to the cipher text) or there is some procedure that I should follow?

Prepending it ("prepend" is not a word in many dictionaries, you could use "prefix" as well) is a common way of handling the IV, yes. The IV may be sent anyway and it doesn't need to be kept confidential. In the case of CBC however it *must* be random, not a sequence number.

Comment: While "prepend" is awkward it is in the [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prepend): *"1.1 Computing Attach (a piece of data) to the beginning of another.
‘in this case, you must prepend the server name to the database name, separated by a period’"*. Also [stackexchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/79324). I find that prefix is *backwards* from the intent, with prefix one must first state what will be prefixed to first followed by the prefix: "prefix 'main thing' with 'first thing' as opposed to prepend: "prepend 'first thing' to 'main thing'".

Comment: @Maarten - thank you for the answer. I understand MAC. whats message sequence number? How would one produce it so as to prevent the said attack?

Comment: The sequence number is required so that an adversary cannot resend the message. How the sequence number is generated doesn't matter as long as it can be verified that repeated messages are not accepted at the receiver. In other words, it is not so much a requirement for the cipher (which just requires an IV, which can possibly be generated from the sequence number) but of the protocol; i.e. it is up to you how to produce it. Sorry for the late reply, I thought I already answered.